# GKE GRPC load balancer https - requirements question

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc

I try to do GRPC client --> GCP external LB with HTTPS --> GKE with pod GRPC server

The external LB uses a google managed certificate.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) states:

> If you are using HTTPS or HTTP/2 from the load balancer to the backends, you must install SSL certificates on each VM instance. To install SSL certificates on a VM instance, use the instructions in your application documentation. These certificates can be self-signed.

So I developped the grpc server with a self-signed certificate.

My question is how the backend service (part of the LB) can call the GRPC server without the server.crt, i.e. the public key of the cert used in the GRPC server?

Is there a way to pass this server.crt to the backend service?

I don't see how to fulfill the documentation requirement.

Please help :)

Comment: Google backends do not validate self-signed certificates. They are just used for encryption.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you know if my use case is currently feasible with GKE? I can't find a working solution. If you have a pointer, I would be interested.

Comment: I don't understand "I can't find a working solution". A working solution for what? The load balancer does not verify self-signed certificates as this is not possible/practical as anyone can create them. The security comes from the load balancer only talking with instances you pre-defined. The certificate is used to encrypt traffic, NOT provide identity.

Comment: @JohnHanley The thing is the LB does not perform healthcheck in http2/grpc. I see no call in my pod from the LB to do health check. Hence LB remains with an unhealthy backend, unusable. Any trial to change the HC to make it work in http2 was unsuccessful.

Comment: You are confusing two different topics in the same question. Create a new question if you have a health check issue with specific configuration details. This has nothing to do with SSL certificates.